# Update database column and fill with false

Tags: android, sql, database

I am trying to update my database to have another column called Visible.  I want the entire column to be filled with false values.  When I run the code, it gets to the update function and kicks out the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: true: UPDATE Themes2 SET Visibility = true;

private static final String TABLE_THEMES_V2 = "Themes2";
public static final String KEY_VISIBLE = "Visibility";

if (oldVersion < 8) {

            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_THEMES_V2 + " ADD COLUMN " + KEY_VISIBLE + " text");
            db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_THEMES_V2 + " SET " + KEY_VISIBLE + " = true;");

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?  I used this same function a long time ago to input "1"s in the columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your KEY_VISIBLE column is having Text data-type so you should update it with following syntax,

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_THEMES_V2 + " SET " + KEY_VISIBLE + " = 'true';");
```

You are just missing `'` single inverted mark in String value.

The alternate way you can try is as follows, by making your KEY_VISIBLE column to integer type

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_THEMES_V2 + " ADD COLUMN " + KEY_VISIBLE + " INTEGER");
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_THEMES_V2 + " SET " + KEY_VISIBLE + " = 1;"); // for True
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_THEMES_V2 + " SET " + KEY_VISIBLE + " = 0;"); // for False
```